# Converting lapply to foreach?

Tags: r, foreach, apply, lapply

I'm hoping to convert the second `lapply` function (`# Make the new list`) into a `foreach` loop, using the `foreach` package.

```
## Example data
lst <- lapply(1:30, function(x) lapply(1:5, function(y) rnorm(10)))

## Make the new list
res <- lapply(1:5, function(x) lapply(1:10, function(y) sapply(lst, function(z) z[[x]][[y]])))
```

I'm not sure if this is possible. I'm not concerned about `lapply` performing better than the `foreach` loops. For context, I'm re-organizing a list of lists of vectors in such a way:

```
new_thing[[5]][[10]][30] <- daily_by_security[[30]][[5]][10]
```

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, The first statement can be rewritten more elegantly using (nested) `replicate`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To figure you how to solve your problem, I looked at the `foreach` examples and the second one does exactly what you are looking for:

```
library("foreach")
example(foreach)

# equivalent to lapply(1:3, sqrt)
foreach(i=1:3) %do%  sqrt(i)
```

I then adapted this to your problem:

```
lst <- lapply(1:30, function(x) lapply(1:5, function(y) rnorm(10)))
resFE <- foreach(i = 1:5) %do% 
                 lapply(1:10, function(y) sapply(lst, function(z) z[[i]][[y]]))
```

**Edit:** The OP was able to figure out a solution based upon my work. Here is the solution:

```
resFE <- foreach(i = 1:5, .packages = "foreach") %dopar% 
                 { foreach(m = 1:10) %dopar% 
                    { foreach(t = lst, .combine = c) %do% 
                     { t[[i]][[m]] } } }
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. I'm hoping to not use any apply functions at all though. Would you know how to change this: `sapply(lst, function(z) z[[i]][[m]])` to a foreach?

Comment: You've welcome. I've got to run, but check out this [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/nested.pdf). I'll look through it more tonight if I have time. I think it does what you want.

Comment: Did you happen to get a chance to take a look? I'm still having some trouble.

Comment: I've done it. Here's the code:
`resFE <- foreach(i = 1:5, .packages = "foreach") %dopar% {
  foreach(m = 1:10) %dopar% {
     foreach(t = lst, .combine = c) %do% {
       t[[i]][[m]]
     }
    
  }
}`

Comment: Glad you could figure it out! I added your solution to my answer

Comment: Also, neat solution! I've look at it a bit more. BTW, the reason I moved your answer from your comment to my answer is that comments are less stable on SO.

Comment: Consider the use of the nested looping operator '%:%'.  As the docs say, you can get more details with the command `vignette("nested")`.